# Shorten Elementor menu underline on hover / selection

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I am I would like to shorten the "underline" in the Elementor header menu of my Wordpress website: [Shortening of header underline - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV4Hq.png)

I used this code to achieve this (I copied it from somewhere else):

```html
.

elementor-widget-nav-menu .elementor-nav-menu--main:not(.e--pointer-framed) .elementor-item:before,
.elementor-widget-nav-menu .elementor-nav-menu--main:not(.e--pointer-framed) .elementor-item:after
{ 
    width: 70%; 
    right: 0; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

**Question 1:** 
Is there a neater / better way to achieve what I want?

**Question 2:** 
If I completely remove "*.elementor-widget-nav-menu .elementor-nav-menu--main:not(.e--pointer-framed) .elementor-item:**before***", my underline still seams to work. Why do I then need this in my code?

As always, thank you.
Michelle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ans 1: There is no other way to do this now.

Ans 2: Only this css should work fine if you put it in your Nav menu widget > Advanced > Custom css tab or in wp customizer if you want to apply it to any other nav menu throughout the site

```
.e--pointer-underline .elementor-item:after {
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
right: 0;
}
```

The other css that you have is used to avoid affecting the other pointer style of nav menu widget such as the frame option.

Answer (score 0):

this code is working properly.good Soykot

```
.e--pointer-underline .elementor-item:after {
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work with a vertical menu, you can do the following menu custom CSS:

```
selector a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on elementor and using menu items from builders like royal addons, then you need to reduce inner horizontal spacing to 0 and increase outer horizontal spacing and it will fix it, thanks. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

Please note that I'm using Elementor Navigation Menu Widget

```
   .hfe-nav-menu__layout-horizontal li.menu-item, .hfe-nav-menu__layout-horizontal > li.menu-item {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.elementor-21 .elementor-element.elementor-element-48d02c5 .menu-item a.hfe-menu-item {
     padding-left: 0px !important; 
     padding-right: 0px !important; 
}
```